# Sitecore 7: Sorting Lucene results by field

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

We're trying to sort our Lucene results by a Title field.

From what I understand from Lucene, this requires the field to be NOT_ANALYZED.

From what I read on the forum, this also requires us using the LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer. ([here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=56600))

I cannot figure out how to get it all together, this is what I have now, and sorting is not working:

In Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration:

```xml
<fields hint="raw:AddCustomField">
  <!--...-->
  <field luceneName="titleForSorting"     storageType="yes" indexType="untokenized">Title</field>
</fields>
```

Our Search result class:

```cs
public class ContentSearchResultItem : SearchResultItem
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    [IndexField("titleForSorting")] 
    public virtual string TitleForSorting { get; set; }
}
```

Our Search implementation:

```cs
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(Context.Indexname).CreateSearchContext())
{
    var query = context.GetQueryable<ContentSearchResultItem>()
        .Where(x => x.Title == "New York")
        .OrderBy(x => x.TitleForSorting);

    var searchResult = query.GetResults();
    var hitsQuery = searchResult.Hits;

    // Or sort here ??
    // hitsQuery = hitsQuery.OrderBy(x => x.Document.TitleForSorting);

    var results = hitsResults.Select(x => x.Document).ToArray();
}
```

As said, I also read we should use the LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer. But cannot figure out where to configure that. The  doesn't seem to provide any place to add the option.

Any help welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct, if you are sorting its best the the field is not tokenized as, if you have spaces etc, it break it up into small tokens and sort on those.

You can specify a custom analyzer as a child of the `field` element in the `fieldMap` section .. e.g

```xml
<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
   <field fieldName="titleForSorting" storageType="YES" indexType="UN_TOKENIZED"    vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
       <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
   </field>
   ...
</fields>
```

(This is valid as of Sitecore 7.0 rev. 130918)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried this, but got a NullReferenceException on `ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(Context.Indexname).CreateSearchContext()`. The TitleForSorting is not actually a field in Sitecore, it is a field I manually added in the `raw:AddCustomField` section

Comment: Did you have the `fieldMap` entry and your custom field entry there at the same time ? If not, try that as the fieldMap should give an analyzer hint when indexing.

Comment: Yes. But I see now: the NullRef exception was because I simplified the field entry under the fieldNames section. Now, I am using your example, and that exception is gone. However, sorting still doesn't work...

Comment: Also, after reindexing, when checking with Luke, the terms for the titleforsorting field are not lowercased. So maybe the problems origin is there?

Comment: Can you try setting the field to be "UN_TOKENIZED" may have been a typo on my part. Also open up the index in Luke and see how that field is stored

Comment: By changing to "UN_TOKENIZED", and reindexing, the values are now indeed lowercased in Luke. However, still no sorting.

Comment: OK, lack of sorting at this point was due to an error of mine after loading the results. By adding the fieldName with the LowerCase analyzer, it works. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this with a custom lucene field name? I'm trying to sort on "Title" which is already indexed tokenised, and I don't want to change it. I'd ideally like to add a new un-tokenised field called "title_for_sort" or something.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is to add **.ToList** after the where clause

```
var query = context.GetQueryable<ContentSearchResultItem>()
        .Where(x => x.Title == "New York")
        .ToList()
        .OrderBy(x => x.TitleForSorting);
```

Comment: Indeed, your sorting for search queries should always occur on the query, not the result stack. Putting it before the GetResults call passes sorting to the search index, which ensures ordering before returning results. Sorting after is sorting only the results you get back. In that case, the only way to sort everything is to get everything, very performance unfriendly.